# React Clerk useUser() Hook user.update not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clerk

Anyone, I can't seem to update the user with user?.update({firstName: "hello"}) with useUser hook with the React SDK. It gives an in promise error in the console. I will provide all screenshots related to the issue.

**Error in console**
[image: Error in console]

**Request in network tab response**
[image: Request in network tab response]

I looked in the console, I looked at the network tab, and it gave an error. In the network tab. I will provide all screenshots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.